# How can I have an image field in a Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to have a feature on my website that allows you to click on a link near an image and have that take you to another page which displays the image and a description. I figured that I could do this with a Model that has an image field and a text field for the description, but I don't know how to store an image!

Is there a function or such that allows you to have an image field in a Django model? If so, what is it and where do I need to store images relative to the models.py file for it to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django.forms has an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) which has a default ClearableFileInput Widget.
It's for when you want to store images uploaded by a user.

If you want to use static images instead, no need to have a field for that in the model. You can work with template tags like `{% if %}` to specify when an image will be shown.

See
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: I wanted to make it such that I can upload the image and write out a description on the admin page. So I should use ImageField, right?

Comment: @AS-Nath yes, ImageField.

Comment: Well, in the end, I used the ImageField and it worked! I basically used it to store the source, and I looped over the list of instances of the Image model, rendered the image at the source, and continued. I'm marking this as correct because without it I wouldn't have gotten anywhere! Thanks so much.